# Spring Integration Junit Bridge a direct channel to testChannel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to write Junits for Spring integration flows and I have a bridge defined to the channel(Direct Channel) for which I want to inspect the message. Since the channel is not Publish Subscribe Channel, the bridge is not recieving the message. I don't want to modify the channel to Publish Subscribe Channel for the purpose of Junit. Is there a way other than making it a Publish Subscribe Channel?

```
<integration:channel id="processResponseChannel1" />
<integration:channel id="processResponseChannel2" />
<integration:channel id="processResponseChannel3" />
<integration:channel id="processResponseChannel4" />

<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="processResponseChannel1" 
    output-channel="processResponseChannel2"                      
    ref="processResponseActivator1"/>

<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="processResponseChannel2" 
    output-channel="processResponseChannel3"                      
    ref="processResponseActivator2"/>

<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="processResponseChannel3" 
    output-channel="processResponseChannel4"                      
    ref="processResponseActivator3"/>
```

I want to retrieve the message in processResponseChannel2 in my junit and perform some assertions on that message.

```
<integration:bridge input-channel="processResponseChannel2" 
output-channel="testChannel"/>

<integration:channel id="testChannel">
  <integration:queue/>
</integration:channel>
```

In Junit, I am using testChannel.receive(5000) to retrieve the message but the test case is failing. 
I don't want to make the processResponseChannel2 as publish subscribe to make the test class work. Is there any other way to retrieve the message in the channel processResponseChannel2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject desired channel as an `AbstractMessageChannel` into your test case and enrich that channel with the `ChannelInterceptor`. In the `preSend()` implementation you can assert incoming messages.

This way your config will stay the same as for tests as for production.